# Calculating Null Space of linear transformation of polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I stumbled upon this True/False question where $T$ is a linear transformation from $P_2$ to $P_2$.

If $T(ax^2 + bx + c) = 2ax + b$, then then a basis for $N(T)$ is $\{−3\}$. The answer was true. I calculated that the basis was $\{1\}$ since $"a"$ and $"b"$ need to be $0$ for the linear transformation to go to $0$, and did not quite understand their answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\{1\}$ is a basis. But so is $\{-3\}$ since $a$ and $b$ are $0$ for $p(x) = -3$ as well.

Comment: Multiplying a vector by a non-zero scalar doesn’t change its span, so the two bases span the same space, namely, the 0-degree (constant) polynomials.

Comment: I see. thank you amd and eepperly, that makes perfect sense. A bit off topic, how do I put a check mark on your answerso the question is solved if you are making comments and not answers.

Comment: You can’t. I’ve added my comment as an answer so that you can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying a vector by a non-zero scalar doesn’t change its span, so the two bases span the same space, namely, the 0-degree (constant) polynomials.